# Sort my IEnumerable<Group> in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class called `Group` containing lots of information retrieved from my database such as as `GroupId` a `Name` or an `Address`.

This is my `Index` controller for my `Group` page that simply displays all of these information in an ordered manner :

All the controller does is get the data and passes it to the View.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{                      
    return View(_service.List());
}
```

I pass the data as an `IEnumerable<Group>` type, but I wonder: how may I order these information in an alphabetical order depending on `Name`?

EDIT: Here is my `Group` class:

```
public partial class Group
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Group()
    {
        this.Companies = new HashSet<Company>();
    }

    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

My `List` method :

```
public IEnumerable<Group> List()
{
    return _repository.List();
}
```

In the repository:

```
public IEnumerable<Group> List()
{
    return _entities.Groups.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so that we can help you with any **specific** problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like this;

```
return View(_service.List().OrderBy(o=>o.Name).ToList());
```

Comment: I can't seem  to use OrderBy because my model does not contain a definition of it. What am I missing? Perhaps a reference?

Comment: see my updated answer. I assume your `List()` method returns a `List<Group>()`

Comment: 'IEnumerable<Group>' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Group>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Maybe I'm not precise enough, sorry

Comment: I've checked your updated answer and get the following error that I have never seen before :'

   System.Web.UI.WebControls.QueryableDataSourceHelper.ToList(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Type)' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: OrderBy is an extension method that works on all `IEnumerable<T>`. You need to add `using system.linq` to the top of your document.

Comment: yes. you need `using system.Linq` in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `OrderBy` method on an `IEnumerable` to sort on a specific key in the object. See also [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx). Note that `OrderBy` is an extension method. So you will need to include the namespace `System.Linq` to be able to use it.

Your code would then become

```
return View(_service.List().OrderBy(g => g.Name));
```